# AngularJS-Creating multiple buttons using ng-repeat each of with different names and functionalities

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create number of buttons using ng-repeat each when clicked should go to different html pages. In the below code I tried using ng-init initializing an array without controller. Is there any other way using ng-repeat. Please help me in this.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="arr1=[{name:'Hyderabad'},{name:'Chennai'},{name:'Pune'}]">
  <input type="button" value="{{x.name}}" ng-repeat="x in arr1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: please post code here, not as image

Comment: <div ng-app="" ng-init="arr1=[{name:'Hyderabad'},{name:'Chennai'},{name:'Bangalore'},{name:'Mumbai'},{name:'Pune'},{name:'Delhi'},{name:'Calcutta'}]">
  <a href="C:\Users\saiswaroop.pullela\Desktop\1 Task\MTICZ\html\home2.html"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default"  value="{{x.name}}" ng-repeat="x in arr1"/></a> 
     </div>

Comment: Please edit the original question to include the code. The code in the comment is not useful.

Comment: I have added sir. At first I have included the code but it is showing some errors.That's why I kept it like an image. Please don't mind. Now I have updated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippit.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="arr1=[{name:'Hyderabad'},{name:'Chennai'},{name:'Pune'}]">
<div ng-repeat="x in arr1">
<a ng-href="{{url you want here based on the logic}}">
  <input type="button" value="{{x.name}}" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I dont know what logic you use to get the url you want to get redirected to for each button. What ever it is, add that  logic to the ng-href section

Comment: Thank you sir. But every time when I wanted to create a new button I have to include it in ng-init. Is there a way that to initialize an array with all the values and call that it in ng-repeat . When ever I initialized that array then a new button should be created.

Comment: You can add that to the $scope with a controller.